# Sdfat .bin to csv file python script

Tags: python, csv, arduino, binary

I am using an Arduino to log some sensor data at 100hz. For this I have modified the [LowLatencyLogger](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/master/SdFat/examples/LowLatencyLogger/LowLatencyLogger.ino) example from the Sdfat library, the program generates a binary file that can be converted to CSV text format using the included binaryToCsv() function but the Arduino takes too long to process the +2million samples that I need. Instead, I am trying to come up with a Python script to convert the BIN file to CSV in my computer but have not been able to. I am sure this must not be too difficult but I am not yet able to understand how the bin file is encoded.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? thanks

Comment: can you post some code you are using?

Comment: I am using a slightly modified version of the LowLatencyLogger code found here: https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/master/SdFat/examples/LowLatencyLogger/LowLatencyLogger.ino
I have not modified the part of the code that encodes the binary file

Comment: instead of put dropbox link to your code, better is post the code direct (security reasons and time saver of people that answers)

Comment: The dropbox link goes to the output .bin file generated by the Arduino, thanks!

Comment: My data looks like this: 

`2,26,3,2017,17,34,48,-282,-2232,15780,5017,-3353,5181,-408,-133,35,-8
10002,26,3,2017,17,34,48,-315,-2273,15746,5017,-3353,5181,-438,-115,35,-8
20002,26,3,2017,17,34,48,-320,-2246,15677,5018,-3349,5189,-437,-106,-7,-8
30004,26,3,2017,17,34,48,-272,-2275,15745,5018,-3349,5189,-400,-131,-25,-8
40004,26,3,2017,17,34,48,-284,-2285,15769,5023,-3364,5201,-420,-151,-57,-7
50004,26,3,2017,17,34,48,-291,-2251,15764,5023,-3364,5201,-397,-133,-27,-7`

Comment: So far I am able to open the file and print its contents using:
`with open("filename", "rb") as binary_file:
 byte = binary_file.read()
 print(byte)`

Which prints:(First few characters of a huge file)
`b'\x07\x00\x00\x00\xc3\x84SU\x00\x1a`
 
Now how do I turn those to good'old text?

Comment: Solved using struct.unpack. The following example reads the first 64 bytes(lenght of each line in my particular CSV) from the file and prints the result:
`import struct
with open("filename", "rb") as binary_file:
    binary_file.seek(8)
    bytes_in_line = binary_file.read(64)
    h = struct.unpack('16i', bytes_in_line)
    print(h)`
Not sure why but had to start at an offset of 8 bytes, otherwise it returned some unknown data.